# TSQL Recursive Query with Count

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, recursion

I have a recursive query that I have working for the most part. Here is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(mgrQID VARCHAR(64), QID VARCHAR(64), NTID VARCHAR(64), FullName VARCHAR(64), lvl int, dt DATETIME, countOfDirects INT)

WITH empList(mgrQID, QID, NTID, FullName, lvl, metadate)
AS
(
       SELECT TOP 1 mgrQID, QID, NTID, FirstName+' '+LastName, 0, Meta_LogDate
       FROM dbo.EmployeeTable_Historical
       WHERE QID IN (SELECT director FROM dbo.attritionDirectors) AND Meta_LogDate <= @pit
       ORDER BY Meta_LogDate DESC

       UNION ALL

       SELECT b.mgrQID, b.QID, b.NTID, b.FirstName+' '+b.LastName, lvl+1, b.Meta_LogDate
       FROM empList a
       CROSS APPLY dbo.Fetch_DirectsHistorical_by_qid(a.QID, @pit)b

)

INSERT INTO @table(mgrQID, QID, NTID, FullName, lvl, dt)
SELECT empList.mgrQID ,
       empList.QID ,
       empList.NTID ,
       empList.FullName ,
       empList.lvl ,
       empList.metadate
FROM empList
ORDER BY lvl
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 10)
```

Now, `@table` has a list of `QIDs` in it. I need to then join my employee table and find out how many people report to each of those `QID's`.

So, there will need to be an `UPDATE` that happens to `@table` which provides the count of employees that report to each of those QID's.

Here is the catch.. The employee table is a historical table that can contain multiple records for the same people. Any time a piece of their information is updated a new record is created with those changes.

If I wanted to pull the most recent record for some one right now, i would use this:

```
SELECT   TOP 1 E.*
FROM     employeeTable_historical AS E
WHERE    E.qid = A.[subQID]
AND CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()) > CONVERT (DATE, E.[Meta_LogDate])
ORDER BY meta_logDate DESC
```

The question..

I need to be able to get the count of employees in the historical table that report directly to each `QID` in the `@table`. The historical table has a column called `mgrQID`. Is there a way I can get this count in the original recursive query?

Comment: First I assume you mean that you need to get the counts of employees that report directly to each QID as at now - bearing in mind there is historical data in the table? The query you show to get the most recent record for someone now, isnt specific to a person, so a modification of this which finds the current-most record for everyone is required. Now I havent tried this, but logically this modified query could then be used as a 2nd CTE in your insert statement, and be queried as a subquery in the whereclause to get the count required by the current QID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend first that you look at the approach you're taking. The historical table you're dealing with will certainly need to select the greatest Meta_LogDate for any given employee, but in the structure you've set up here, you'll never select more than one record from matching attritionDirectors, thanks to the `TOP 1` in your anchor query. As such, I'd recommend a lightweight function on which you base your query:

```
create function dbo.EmployeesAsOf(@date datetime)
returns table
as return 
    select mgrQID, QID, NTID, FirstName, LastName, Meta_LogDate
    from dbo.EmployeeTable_Historical A
    where Meta_LogDate = (select max(Meta_LogDate) from dbo.EmployeeTable_Historical B where A.QID = B.QID and Meta_LogDate <= @date)
```

This will allow you to get the most recent record for anyone, and as long as EmployeeTable_Historical has an index on (QID, Meta_LogDate), this view will perform well.

Having said that, looking at your recursive query, you'll likely want to tweak the recursive query somewhat:

```
create function empList(@thisDate datetime)
returns @emptbl table (
      mgrQID varchar(10)
    , QID varchar(10)
    , NTID varchar(10)
    , Name varchar(21)
    , Meta_LogDate datetime
    , DirectsThisMany int
)
as 
begin
    ;with empList AS (
        select E.mgrQID, E.QID, E.NTID, E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS Name, E.Meta_LogDate
        from dbo.EmployeesAsOf(@thisDate) E
            inner join dbo.attritionDirectors D on E.QID = D.QID
        union all
        select E.mgrQID, E.QID, E.NTID, E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS Name, E.Meta_LogDate
        from dbo.EmployeesAsOf(@thisDate) E
            inner join empList D on E.mgrQID = D.QID
    )
    insert into @emptbl
        select A.mgrQID, A.QID, A.NTID, A.Name, A.Meta_LogDate, count(b.QID) AS DirectsThisMany
        from empList A
            left join empList B on A.QID = B.mgrQID
        group by A.mgrQID, A.QID, A.NTID, A.Name, A.Meta_LogDate
    return
end
```

In this way, you'll be able to feed in any date and get a read of the tables, including counts from history as of that date. The self-join of the CTE is what enables us to get the current count of directs, as one can't use aggregates in the CTE. This function is easy to use, and the indexing strategy should become apparent by looking at the query plan in SSMS. A simple `SELECT * FROM EmpList(GETDATE())` will give the current situation.

Comment: I am a little confused on the second code block - is that a second function?

Comment: I got both functions created and it took 2:51 to run and then gave the error of  `Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
`

Comment: Feel free to adjust the data types of the returned table from either to match your schema. Without DDL for all tables involved, I was going on examples.